# Restrict user access to pages

Tags: django, restriction

I want users to be able to see only their profile information and not have acccess to others users information. I am using a test_func to check if the user login trying to access the profile information is the owner of the information.
The problem is that for some reason it always returns true, and when i go to my page an change the id on the link trying to access others users information it somehow automatically login with the user due user account and then return the information, it is, if i'm logged in as "lerton" with id 1 and i try to access the information of user "maguia" with id 2 it automatically log in as "maguia" and return me the information of "maguia"

**urls.py**

```
path('profile/<int:pk>/', ProfileView.as_view(), name='profile'),
```

**View.py**

```
class ProfileView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView, UserPassesTestMixin):
    model = get_user_model()
    template_name = 'profile.html'
    context_object_name = 'user'
    
    def test_func(self):
        user = self.get_object()
        return user == self.request.user
```

I tried to compare in the test_func the other properties like id, username, etc, of the users but didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below code to check if current user and given user is same:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.views.generic import DetailView

class ProfileView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = get_user_model()
    template_name = 'profile.html'
    context_object_name = 'user'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        # Ensure that the user can only access their own profile
        obj = super().get_object(queryset)
        if obj != self.request.user:
            # If the user is trying to access someone else's profile, raise a 404 error
            raise Http404("You are not allowed to access this page.")
        return obj
```

Or you can try dispatch method:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.views.generic import DetailView
from django.http import Http404

class ProfileView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = get_user_model()
    template_name = 'profile.html'
    context_object_name = 'user'

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = self.get_object()
        if obj != self.request.user:
            raise Http404("You are not allowed to access this page.")
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked, the problem now is that the message i passed as argument in Http404() is not beeing displayed in the template but maybe because i have DEBUG set to True.

Comment: Yes, you have to set DEBUG to False to display that error message

Comment: You can accept the answer (if it helps you) by clicking on big gray check button on its left side.